# Configs loads only when configs are published

Tags: laravel, config, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to build a package for my application and there some `config` files that user can publish and modify configs (like every `laravel` package).

I recently noticed that the config file are loads only when the user publishes config files.

Here is my package repo on GitHub: [Laravel Adobe Connect Client](https://github.com/soheilrt/laravel-adobe-connect-client)

Here is my **service provider**:

```php
class AdobeConnectServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__ . "/config/adobeConnect.php", 'adobeConnect');
        $this->bindFacades();
    }

    /**
     * Bind Facades
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function bindFacades()
    {
        $config = $this->getAdobeConfig();
        $entities = $config["entities"];

        $this->app->singleton(Client::class, function () {
            return $this->processClient();
        });

        $this->app->bind('sco', function () use ($entities) {
            return new $entities["sco"]();
        });
        $this->app->bind('sco-record', function () use ($entities) {
            return new $entities["sco-record"]();
        });
        $this->app->bind('principal', function () use ($entities) {
            return new $entities["principal"]();
        });
        $this->app->bind('permission', function () use ($entities) {
            return new $entities["permission"]();
        });
        $this->app->bind('common-info', function () use ($entities) {
            return new $entities["common-info"]();
        });
        $this->app->singleton('adobe-connect', function () {
            return App::make(Client::class);
        });

    }

    /**
     * get Adobe Connect Client Config
     *
     * @return array|null
     */
    private function getAdobeConfig()
    {
        return $this->app["config"]->get("adobeConnect");
    }

    /**
     * login adobe client in case of there is no session configured
     *
     * @return Client
     */
    private function processClient()
    {
        $config = $this->getAdobeConfig();

        $connection = new Connection($config["host"], $config["connection"]);
        $client = new Client($connection);

        if ($config["session-cache"]["enabled"]) {
            $this->loginClient($client);
        }

        return $client;
    }

    /**
     * Login Client Based information that introduced in environment/config file
     *
     * @param Client $client
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function loginClient(Client $client)
    {
        $config = $this->getAdobeConfig();
        $driver = $this->getCacheDriver();

        $session = Cache::store($driver)->remember(
            $config['session-cache']['key'],
            $config['session-cache']['timeout'],
            function () use ($config, $client) {
                $client->login($config["user-name"], $config["password"]);
                return $client->getSession();
            });

        $client->setSession($session);
    }

    /**
     * get Preferred cache driver
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    private function getCacheDriver()
    {
        $config = $this->app["config"]->get("adobeConnect");
        if ($driver = $config["session-cache"]["driver"]) {
            return $driver;
        }
        return $this->app["config"]->get("cache.default");
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/config/adobeConnect.php' => config_path('adobeConnect.php'),
        ], 'adobe-connect');
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            SCORecord::class,
            Principal::class,
            Permission::class,
            CommonInfo::class,
            Client::class,
            SCO::class,
            'adobe-connect'
        ];
    }
}
```

I've read `laravel's` official [package](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages) and I've found nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. the problem resists under defer loading provider:
It should return facade binding names instead of the class name.

```php
    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            Client::class,
            'sco-record',
            'principal',
            'permission',
            'common-info',
            'sco',
            'adobe-connect'
        ];
    }
```